# Adding items to menu in winforms/c# to open apps

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-3.0

As part of a small program I am writing, I need to progmatically add items to a menustrip. The main app will run on a thumb drive, and I'd like users to input the name of the aditional third party apps and then browse to their executables. Once I know the location, I'd like to add the app name to a menustrip and have them be able to use the menustrip item as a shortcut.

My question is what is the best way to go about launching the app. I can add items to the menu, but I'm not sure how to make them actually point to the apps. It needs to be persistent too. Should I store app names and paths in XML or something and look up the path based on the value of the menustrip? I feel like I should know the answer to this problem, but maybe I'm just coming at it from the wrong angle.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to use [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx)

More specifically, you will want to initialize it with process info that allows you to get feedback from the process.

Create a method that wraps the logic and allows you to toss in your command line arguments, as well as your executable path.  (remember quotes for paths, etc.)

```
public void LaunchApplication(string fullPath, string args)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process AppLaunch = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    AppLaunch.Exited += new EventHandler(Process_Exited);
    AppLaunch.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    AppLaunch.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    AppLaunch.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    AppLaunch.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    AppLaunch.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    AppLaunch.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
    AppLaunch.StartInfo.FileName = fullPath;
    AppLaunch.Start();
}
```

By handling the exit events and redirecting outputs and inputs you have a lot more control over the process.  `UseShellExecute`determines if there is a command window that shows up when the application launches (true means it will).

You can find the documentation on MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

Using this approach gives you a lot of freedom over how you handle things like the user closing the application.  Or if an application needs special authentication you can set those values using something like:

```
System.Security.SecureString securePass = new                  
                  System.Security.SecureString();

foreach (char c in password)
{
     securePass.AppendChar(c);
}

AppLaunch.StartInfo.Domain = domain;
AppLaunch.StartInfo.UserName = user;
AppLaunch.StartInfo.Password = securePass;
```

I would probably persist the app paths and arguments in XML.  Any user credentials needed I'd likely store encrypted (and obfuscated) in some storage format.  Although I am pretty sure it's not considered a "best approach", I have also used XML for this in the past where the elements were named as follows:

```
<value-x>{encryptedUserName}</value-x>
<value-y>{encryptedDomainName}</value-y>
<value-z>{encryptedPassword}</value-z>
```

Comment: Thanks! How to I tie the click event for the menu item to LaunchApplication()?

Comment: You would basically look at your sender in your click event to see which menu item was clicked.  This could be used as a key to retrieve the  XML Element containing your info.   

i.e. 
`<launch-item  
      menuKey="mnu_LaunchMicrosoftWebsite" 
      path="c:\program files (x86)\Google\chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
      args="www.microsoft.com" />`

Then you'd simply call LaunchApplication() with the info you pull from the XML.   You could possibly even store it in the menu item itself.